# True or false: $x^{T}A^{T}Ax\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem:

For matrix with $m\times n$ and for every $x\in \mathbb R^{n}$ :

$x^{T}A^{T}Ax\geq 0$

Any tip how to start?

I am thinking about semi-positive matrices, but I am not sure.

**My try:**

$x^{T}A^{T}Ax=(Ax)^{T}(Ax)$

Comment: $y^{T}y \geq 0$ for any $y$. Put $y=Ax$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = Ax$. Then, $x^\top A ^\top A x = y^\top y = \Vert y \Vert_2^2 \geq0$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$x^TA^TAx = (Ax)^T Ax$. Now use a well known property of the inner product.

Comment: I was editing cause I had same idea and we posted at same time :D